# Getting error trying to pass data to child component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular &I have a component as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  blogpost;
   ngOnInit() {
       this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/demo/all").
      subscribe(function(data){
        this.blogpost=data;
        console.log(this.blogpost);
      })

   }
}
```

blogpost field contains an array of blogposts obejects
and here is the template associated with component

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><app-blog-post [title]="blogpost[0].title"></app-blog-post></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">456</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">123</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">456</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but value passed from this template is not showing in the child component,and I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
here is the child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post',
  templateUrl: './blog-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-post.component.css']
})
export class BlogPostComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  @Input() title:String="abc";
}
```

and child template

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong. Please somebody help me with this

Comment: `<app-blog-post [title]="blogpost?.length ? blogpost[0].title : ''"></app-blog-post>` should work I believe, or else, simply add a check if blogpost exists. like: `blogpost && blogpost.length ... etc`

Comment: This solution is so ugly... why trying to get length of a non existing array ? Just test the very existence of the array. Also this is a case for what *ngIf is for, no need to initiate a component with non-wanted data (empty title) just initiate it when http call is done.

Answer (score 1):

Move **blogpost** to out of the constructor then declare it as

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
public blogpost: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   ngOnInit() {
       this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/demo/all").
      subscribe(function(data){
        this.blogpost=data;
        console.log(this.blogpost);
      })

   }
}
```

Comment: If I don't use [title]="blogpost[0].title" in html template it shows default string "abc" but when I pass data from parent component it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t forget that http calls are asynchronous so your Post list is not defined before your get request is completed. And so index 0 of undefined is invalid. One solution could be to use ˋ*ngIf="!!blogpost" on app-blog-post component.

A better solution could be using async pipe. Here is a good example : https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794

Comment: Why is it `*ngIf="!!blogpost"` and not just `*ngIf="blogpost"`?